# Project sharing Authorization 'REPO.MAINTAIN_NATIVE_PACKAGES' missing in HANA

Tags: eclipse, cloud, hana

Today I installed SAP HANA development plugins which are available at [Repo](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/luna) for Eclipse LUNA .

I followed [SAP HANA Cloud Platform](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?3762b229a4074fc59ac6a9ee7404f8c9.html) to create a project and to install tool I followed SAP [Development Tools for Eclipse](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/)

When I tried to share a project to SAP HANA Repository then it gives error as

> Authorization 'REPO.MAINTAIN_NATIVE_PACKAGES' missing for package 'hello' or one of its parent packages.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your admin has to give your SAP Cloud Platform user the proper permissions to do it. In this case the "REPO.MAINTAIN_NATIVE_PACKAGES" permission